# Google Contacts API key expires in a few days; how to lengthen duration?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, command-line-interface, contacts

I'm using [goobook](https://gitlab.com/goobook/goobook) as a command-line Google Contacts query tool, using the instructions provided [here](https://gitlab.com/goobook/goobook) to create a client on the cloud console and then authenticate from the command-line (using a headless session). The token only lasts a few days and then the tools needs re-authentication. I don't see a setting in the Google Cloud Console to lengthen the token expiration time -- is this something I need to change in the goobook code, in the cloud console, or somewhere else?

Running the tool every hour to keep the token fresh does not help.

Per a comment, the command I am using is:

```
goobook authenticate --noauth_local_webserver -- [CLIENT ID] [CLIENT SECRET]
```

The goobook authentication code (which I did not write) is [here](https://gitlab.com/goobook/goobook/-/blob/main/goobook/application.py?ref_type=heads), I believe in relevant part:

```
import oauth2client.client
import oauth2client.file
import oauth2client.tools
...
    parser_auth = subparsers.add_parser('authenticate',
                                        description=AUTHENTICATE_HELP_STRING,
                                        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                        parents=[oauth2client.tools.argparser])
    parser_auth.add_argument('client_id', metavar='CLIENT_ID',
                             help='Client ID')
    parser_auth.add_argument('client_secret', metavar='CLIENT_SECRET',
                             help='Client secret')
    parser_auth.set_defaults(func=do_authenticate)
...
def do_authenticate(config, args):
    store = config.store
    creds = config.creds

    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(args.client_id, args.client_secret, SCOPES)
        creds = oauth2client.tools.run_flow(flow, store, args)
    else:
        print('You are already authenticated.')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code